# Differential amplifier input voltage

Tags: amplifier

I have this schematic

[image: Amplifier]

The e- is connected to a resistance R1 and a voltage source V1.
The e+ is connected to a resistance R2 and a voltage source V2.

I want to calculate the differential input voltage.

[image: My work]

Comment: ...that means: You want somebody else to calculate, correct?

Comment: Actually, I did but I'm not sure about the result

Comment: Share your calculation and others can clarify your doubts

Comment: @Umar I just edited the post.

Comment: @zerocoldTUN: If, as you wrote, "e- is connected to a resistance R1 **and** a voltage source V1" the potential at e- will be V1. Similar for e+: it  will be at potential V2. So the difference would be V1-V2. Did you mean one terminal of R1 is connected to e- and the other terminal of R1 is connected to a voltage source V1?

Comment: @Curd the goal of this application is to calculate the input voltage before supposing that [1]: http://www.sciweavers.org/upload/Tex2Img_1484140635/render.png

Comment: Please use a textual description that is consistent with the schematic. The schematic doesn't show any of the following: R1, R2, V1, V2. So how are others supposed to know what you mean?

Comment: @Curd I edited the post again! Sorry, this is my first time here